# How to debug popen() not working?

Tags: php, windows, background-process, popen

On my Linux server I use `shell_exec()` to run scripts asynchronously. This function is not available on Windows, which I use for development, and so I am trying to use `popen()` instead.

I am running Windows 10 x64, WampServer 2.5 x32 (PHP 5.5.12).

I have the following code in a PHP file:

```
$cmd = '"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe" "C:\wamp\www\path\to\file.php" "arg1" "arg2"';

        echo 'Running on DEV MACHINE: ' . $cmd . PHP_EOL;
        $handle = popen("start /B " . $cmd, "r");
        if ($handle === FALSE) {
            die("Unable to execute $cmd");
        }
        pclose($handle);
```

The script executes without any errors, but the PHP files are never run. I know they aren't being run because I put an SQL query at the very top to update a field in a database to indicate they have been run.

As you can see in the above code, I print out the command being passed to `popen()`. If I paste that command into command prompt and execute it, the scripts run fine. This proves the issue lies with `popen()`.

Am I using `popen()` incorrectly somehow? How can I debug what the problem is? Normally I would debug using XDebug, but there's no way to use that in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get my code working, but I found an alternative method from another answer on here and based on that changed my code to use the following and it works:

```
$WshShell = new \COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```

Comment: did you try : `pclose(popen("start /B " . $cmd, "r"));`?

Comment: @Anthony that's exactly what I have in my question if you look at the code. It wouldn't work for some reason.

Comment: No, you have popen() then an error check, then pclose(). I'm suggesting pclose(popen()), where the popen is inside a pclose. If you look at the code, you'll see the difference.

Comment: @Anthony That is how I originally had it, but I changed it to the way it is in my question so that I *could* check for errors since I was trying to debug. The code is equivalent in any case..